# Convert array to hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on implementing graphs in rails app. There is a specific data format requirement. I  am have the data as below:

```
["counting", [50, 50, 50, 50]]
```

The required format is

```
{:name=>"counting", :data=>[350, 350, 250, 150]}
```

Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple

```
array = ["counting", [50, 50, 50, 50]]
required_format = { name: array.first, data: array.last } #=> {:name=>"counting", :data=>[50, 50, 50, 50]}
```

Alternatively

```
array = ["counting", [50, 50, 50, 50]]
keys = [:name, :data]
required_format = keys.zip(array).to_h #=> {:name=>"counting", :data=>[50, 50, 50, 50]}
```